# Copy a string from MatToggleButton into Angular 5 Autocomplete input field

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I am new to angular, so I hope this is not painfully obvious.

Short description:
I am trying to copy a string into an Angular Material Autocomplete Formfield by clicking a MatToggleButton. So far I managed to change the value of the underlying model, but not the string displayed in the field. If nothing has been selected from the Autocomplete and I press the button, the text gets copied. If in between something is selected from the Autocomplete, I do not get the text of the input displayed.

Long description: I tried the following to fill the Autocomplete by using the `MatButtonToggleChange`. The Selections in the list come from a Solr-Server in Production, therefore the interface for `Document` and the structuring of the example `Results`. When a value from the Autocomplete gets selected, it returns an object instead of a string, so the `displayFn` function extracts the string-type label and displays that. I tried to overload that function to also accept strings, but that didn't help either.

HTML

```
<div class="example-btn-list">
  <mat-button-toggle-group (change)="fillExample($event)">
    <mat-button-toggle class="example-buttons" *ngFor="let example of exampleQueries" selected="false" [value]="example">
     {{example.searchTerm}}
    </mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" hintLabel="Enter some Art related input">
    <input #searchField matInput placeholder="Art Search Term" aria-label="Search Field" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="searchCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let result of Result" [value]="result">
        <small>Type: {{ result.type }}</small> &nbsp;
        <span>{{ result.label }}</span>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInput, MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent, MatButtonToggleChange } from '@angular/material';
import { Document } from './app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Autocomplete Minimal Example';

  constructor( ) { }

  public exampleQueries = [
    {
      ptType: 'Painting',
      type: 'painting',
      searchTerm: 'Odalisque with Slave'
    }
  ];


  public Result = [
    {
      'type': 'painting',
      'label': ['Grande Odalisque'],
    },
    {
      'type': 'painting',
      'label': ['Odalisque with Slave'],
    },
  ];

  public searchCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  @ViewChild('SearchField')
  public SearchField: ElementRef;

  public displayFn( document?: string | Document): string | undefined {
    if ( document && typeof document === 'object') {
    return document ? document.label : undefined;
    } else if ( typeof document === 'string') {
      return document;
    }
  }


  public fillExample(e: MatButtonToggleChange): void {
    this.searchCtrl.setValue(e.source.value.searchTerm);
    console.log(e.source.value.searchTerm);
    this.SearchField = e.source.value.searchTerm;
    console.log(this.SearchField);
  }

}
```

app.ts

```
export interface Document {
  type: string;
  label: string;
}
```

Am I missing something? 
How do I copy a string into an Autocomplete?

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/jPtSpZ?p=info

Answer (score 0):

Your plunkr doesn't run. And you have mistakes. Case matters: `#searchField` and `@ViewChild('SearchField')` do not match. You have only one toggle button so it can only be pressed once (no way to un-toggle).

As for your problem - keep in mind that setting the form control value to a string does not cause a selection from the autocomplete - you have to manage that yourself by setting the form control value to the matching `Document` list item not the text. That might mean doing a manual search if the button represents text, or it may be better to associate the `Document` object directly with the button.

Another overall problem is that typing in to the field does nothing. An autocomplete is supposed to filter/search items based on input text, but you have not implemented this.